# Squid3: allow some site only for some user

Tags: server, proxy

I've a squid3 proxy on my server ubuntu.

I would allow access to a group of sites only to a group of users.
Now my simple code is this:

```
acl WHITELIST url_regex "/var/proxy/whitelist/test.whitelist"
http_access allow WHITELIST
http_access deny all
```

In to test there is only "google.it" and the proxy works.

In the server there is another user, named "test_user" with password "password".

My first problem is: how can i set in squid config on server to allow only Whitelist for only user/group?

Second problem: On the client (with Lubuntu), what should I config? I try to config /etc/environment like this:

```
export http_proxy=http://test_user:password@myserverip:2888/
export https_proxy=http://test_user:password@myserverip:2888/
export ftp_proxy=http://test_user:password@myserverip:2888/
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
export HTTP_PROXY=http://test_user:password@myserverip:2888/
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://test_user:password@myserverip:2888/
export FTP_PROXY=http://test_user:password@myserverip:2888/
NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

EDIT:
in my proxy setting I've set user and it works, but on lubuntu client firefox always ask me for password..

/etc/environment is like this:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://simone:simone@192.168.0.199:2888/
```

Comment: Nobody can help me..?

Answer (score 0):

1. prepare file contains list of user(s)
2. prepare file contains list of sites(s)
3. map them in squid.conf as below

   ```
   acl userlist src "/home/acl/userlist"  
   acl whitelist urlpath_regex "/home/acl/whitelist"    
   http_access allow userlist sitelist
   ```

done.

for your second problem ,

the port number for squid3 is 3128.
so change the port number.
and you can configure your proxy settings in /etc/apt/apt.conf file
as below:

```
https_proxy=http://test_user:password@myserverip:3128
```

note: if apt.conf file not available, create it.

Thats all !