# How to easily get all HTTPS addresses that an application connects to externally?

Tags: security, firewall, network-monitoring

For those who have a firewall with highly restrictive outputs, they only need to release supposedly reliable addresses for each application, so I was wondering if there is any software or command line that I can easily monitor and find out what are the URLs (HTTPS) that the application connect?

Right now, I'm looking to know all the addresses of WordPress and its plugins, which addresses they need to connect to update them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of command line options.

#### Use `watch` with `lsof`

From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144004/97255) to [Monitor outgoing web requests as they’re happening](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/141600/97255), you could use `lsof` and `watch`.

To quote the answer in its entirety:

> You can use `lsof` and `watch` to do this, like so:
>
> ```
> $ watch -n1 lsof -i TCP:80,443
> ```
>
> #### Example output
>
> ```
> dropbox    3280 saml   23u  IPv4 56015285      0t0  TCP greeneggs.qmetricstech.local:56003->snt-re3-6c.sjc.dropbox.com:http (ESTABLISHED) 
> thunderbi  3306 saml   60u  IPv4 56093767      0t0  TCP greeneggs.qmetricstech.local:34788->ord08s09-in-f20.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED) 
> mono       3322 saml   15u  IPv4 56012349      0t0  TCP greeneggs.qmetricstech.local:54018->204-62-14-135.static.6sync.net:https (ESTABLISHED) 
> chrome    11068 saml  175u  IPv4 56021419      0t0  TCP greeneggs.qmetricstech.local:42182->stackoverflow.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
> ```

I have just tried it and it is pretty useful. You could reduce the repeat time to 0.1 seconds if you use `-n0`.

---

#### Just `lsof`

From [Monitoring files continuously with lsof](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157064/97255), you could dispense with `watch` and use just `lsof` in conjunction with the repeat (`-r`) option. The following repeats every two seconds

```
$ lsof -i TCP:80,443 -r 2
```

but the output isn't as pretty, although the past connections are better preserved:

```
=======
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox 9542 user   27u  IPv4 1068219      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:37360->192.0.78.23:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 9542 user   48u  IPv4 1053405      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:45948->ec2-54-213-37-69.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
=======
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox 9542 user   27u  IPv4 1068219      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:37360->192.0.78.23:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 9542 user   48u  IPv4 1053405      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:45948->ec2-54-213-37-69.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 9542 user   52u  IPv4 1138942      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:57602->kul08s01-in-f10.1e100.net:https (SYN_SENT)
firefox 9542 user  102u  IPv4 1139934      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:49102->kul09s13-in-f14.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 9542 user  110u  IPv4 1138950      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:49104->kul09s13-in-f14.1e100.net:https (SYN_SENT)
=======
...
=======
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox 9542 user   27u  IPv4 1068219      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:37360->192.0.78.23:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 9542 user   48u  IPv4 1053405      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:45948->ec2-54-213-37-69.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 9542 user   51u  IPv4 1140129      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:52284->kul09s13-in-f10.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 9542 user  108u  IPv4 1137384      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:55886->103.229.10.236:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 9542 user  122u  IPv4 1137399      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:55870->kul08s12-in-f1.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 9542 user  126u  IPv4 1137402      0t0  TCP user-300V3Z-300V4Z-300V5Z:47370->stackoverflow.com:https (SYN_SENT)
```

**Note**: Every two seconds interval is separated by `=======`.

---

See also [how to find URLs accessed by a process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/188644/97255), although, given the promising title, the two answers unfortunately don't *seem* to provide a filter on a per application, or per process, basis.

Other useful tricks with `lsof` are described here, [15 Linux lsof Command Examples (Identify Open Files)](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/lsof-command-examples/), which would allow you to filter the results of `lsof` more, so that you can customise the commands above to more your taste.

Comment: While `lsof` is a nice quick option and my own first thought, it is point-in-time and ephemeral when compared to a proxy that is persistent and will actually help with the first sentence of the question regarding restricting trusted hosts. So the proxy answers all aspect of the question but the limited`lsof` was accepted? In production there are better options - what is in Ubuntu repos? squid proxy seems the best fit for reliable deployment to solve this question whereas lsof is a troubleshooting tool only

Answer (score -2):

A tool called a "proxy" is likely what you need, I see "Zap" in snapcraft when I search for "proxy" and that is a good tool provided by Ubuntu repositories. This 'proxy" thing can be quite technical but it is precisely the technique you are asking about, there is nothing specific to Ubuntu (or any operating system) that addresses your question but a proxy can help you.

See: https://snapcraft.io/install/zaproxy/ubuntu

Run using these instructions: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/cmdline/ i.e. for Ubuntu: `java -jar zap.jar`. Then you can configure your system proxy (typically `export https_proxy='http://localhost:8080'`.

If you run this on your PC, not on the same server as Wordpress, then you may need to configure a Wordpress plugin such as: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-proxy/

Zap also needs to be configured to intercept HTTP traffic specifically, these are those instructions: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/ui/dialogs/options/dynsslcert/

Once this is running, you will see all HTTPS traffic in the Zap graphical interface.

For a production deployment that can whitelist, there is a good answer here: [Squid3: allow some site only for some user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591756/squid3-allow-some-site-only-for-some-user)

Good luck! Investigations into network traffic can be fun if not daunting at first